# Swagger Annotation for enum as a component

Tags: java, enums, swagger, openapi

I have an enum:

```java
public enum UserType {
  ADMIN("Admin"),
  GUEST("Guest"),
  SUPERVIOR("Supervisor"),
  NORMAL("Normal");

  private final String type;

  UserType(final String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
```

And I'm using it as a query parameter with Swagger annotation:

```java
@GET
@AsyncTimed
@Path("/all")
void all(
    @ApiParam @PathParam(USER_ID) @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.PATH, name = USER_ID, required = true) final UserId userId,
    @QueryParam(TYPES) final Set<UserType> userTypes,
    @Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse
);
```

The generated OpenAPI file, however, is not creating a component out of the enum and instead is giving:

```
get:
  parameters:
  - name: UserId
    in: path
    required: true
    schema:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserId'
  - name: Types
    in: query
    schema:
      uniqueItems: true
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
        enum:
          - ADMIN
          - GUEST
          - SUPERVISOR
          - NORMAL
```

Is there a way to make the enum a component schema instead? If I use this enum in other components, those components also use `enum:` instead of a `$ref`.

Comment: You may need to annotate the enum and/or the corresponding parameter with `@Schema(..., enumAsRef=true)`.

Comment: @Helen wonderful; if you post this as an answer I can mark it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to annotate the enum and/or the corresponding parameter with `@Schema(..., enumAsRef=true)`.